# Visual Studio doesn't update cshtml file when debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, razor, visual-studio-2012

I have made some changes to my cshtml file to debug a bug (a horse of course).  But the changes aren't reflected when I actually debug even though I saved the file?  This is very strange behavior.  Are the CSHTML files cached somewhere in a magical directory?  If so where.  If not how can I clear my cache so as to debug the problem?

**UPDATE: Looking over the loaded modules**

After recalling how I debug some issues attaching to a WCF service, I decided to see if I could find the locally loaded symbols on my machine.  I was able to navigate to the temporary ASP.net Files\root directory.  Their I searched for the cshtml file that has been throwing fits at me.  What I got was the file name with an appended suffix added to it .a2269a6c_CBMResult.ccu.  Does any body know what that file name means and how it relates to the original file.  If I delete it, will asp.net regenerate the file and thus refresh the cshtml file?

Comment: cshtml files aren't cached somewhere in a directory unless you defined it.
Did you try to change browser for your tests ?

Comment: I tried chrome, IE 9 and Firefox.  The file is never changed for any reason.

Comment: How does one log a bug with Microsoft?  This is extremely frustrating.   Being able to edit your own source code is paramount to successful development

Comment: anybody ever have this problem?  I am flumoxed?

Comment: Maybe you update a site which is not located to the good pool ; did you try to recycle the application pool ? Restart IIS server ?

Comment: This is all in the Visual studio debugger.  I tried a different site with a new instance of visual studio 2012, and that gave me a different site, but when I came back to my old site, the code still wasn't updated.

Comment: What is driving me crazy, if I change another file, it shows when I debug.  Why on Earth would that one page, not update?

Comment: Did you try to Clean/Rebuild Solution ?

Comment: Are you using a custom `VirtualPathProvider`?

Comment: I'm seeing this too.  I've tried shutting everything down and rebuilding several times.  When I recompile and run, the pages are refreshed, but when I make changes while the site is live, I don't see any of my changes.  It used to work, then at one point stopped.  It works with css and js files, but not cshtml pages.  I don't know if it has anything to do with this, but I'm using MVC 5.2.3 and the Azure compute emulator.

Comment: I'm using MVC 5.2.3 and I actually deleted the file, and still the page was being served up. Tried a clean & rebuild, still nothing.